# Calculating angle in a pyramid

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question "Calculate the angle between the length AE and the base ABCD in the pyramid pictured below, giving your answer to 1 decimal place."

[image]

For this question I know we have to find the angle A. Firstly what I done is I dissected the pyramid through the middle from E so that I can form a right angled triangle.

I then used Pythagoras to find the length of side AE and the line though the middle.

I then used the Sine rule to try and find the angle A in which I got 81.7 degrees, however the solutions say that the answer should be 77.8 degrees.

Here is my working:

[image]

[image]

Where have I gone wrong ?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Two notes

1) isn't the length of $AE$ given as 10cm?

2) In Pythagorian theorem i think you should put $9/4$ instead of $3^2$
as it's half the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle you actually want is $\angle EAC$, so you need $$\cos^{-1}\frac{3}{10\sqrt{2}}=77.8^o$$

Comment: Can I just ask how you got $frac\{3}{10\sqrt{2}$ ? Thanks :)

Comment: The centre of the base square is the foot of the perpendicular from the vertex and is the midpoint of $AC$ which has length $3\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I understand this. But when I use the cosine rule I get the answer 67.04 degrees. Please could you see my edit ? Thanks :)

Comment: $EA=10$ not $\sqrt{118}$

Comment: Okay thanks I understand now :)